# Attempting PDE with inequality in boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am attempting to solve the equation below, which requires `v[y,0]==0` for all y greater than 0. I have followed the `/;` approach to enforce this definition, as outlined in the DSolve/Delay Differential Equations page in the language documentation.

`DSolve[{Derivative[2,0][v][y,t]==Derivative[0,1][v][y,t],v[0,t]==1,v[y/;y>0]==0},v[y,t],{y,t}]`

Wolfram simply outputs the cell back without an error message. I believe that my inequality restriction on y in the second boundary condition is the issue, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I want to solve on {y, 0, Infinity}. The problem is startup of Couette flow.

Comment: Do you want an analytical solution or a numerical one?

Comment: I want an analytical solution, which I am confident exists

Comment: The solution exists on the half-line. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
sol= DSolve[{Derivative[2, 0][v][y, t] == Derivative[0, 1][v][y, t], 
       v[0, t] == 1, v[y, 0] == 0}, v, {y, 0, Infinity}, {t, 0, Infinity}]
    Plot3D[Evaluate[v[y, t] /. First[sol]], {y, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 10}, 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: fig1]